# Как разрешить одному блоку увеличивать внешний, а другому только заполнять?

Tags: html, css

Есть внешний div - content-wrapper. Вложенный в него text-wrapper может увеличивать свои размеры в высоту. При этом, расширяет content-wrapper. Но также есть image-wrapper, который должен заполнять по высоте content-wrapper. Проблема в том, что картинка может быть больше чем нужно, в итоге будет самостоятельно растягивать content-wrapper. Итого - блок text-wrapper может расширять content-wrapper, а image-wrapper должен его только заполнять(на 100% по высоте), но не расширять. Интересует и желательно решение только на css.

HTML:

```
<div class="book-element">
                    <div class="content-wrapper">
                        <div class="image-wrapper">
                            <img src="img.jpg" alt="bookImage"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-wrapper">
                            <div class="text-wrapper1">
                                <span class="field-descr">Название: </span>Eragon<br>
                                <span class="field-descr">Автор: </span>Cristofer Paoloni<br>
                                <span class="field-descr">Жанр: </span>Фантастика<br>
                                <span class="field-descr">Издательство: </span>хз<br>
                                <span class="field-descr">Кол-во страниц: </span>100500<br>
                                <span class="field-descr">ISBN: </span>123-12345-123-1-1
                                123-12345-123-1-1 123-12345-123-1-1
                                <br>
                                <span class="field-descr">Язык: </span>Русский<br>
                                <!--<span> </span>-->
                                <!--<br>-->
                                <!--<span></span>-->
                                <!--<br>-->
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-wrapper2">
                                <div class="description">
                                    <span>This is a book. This book contains some test. This text is about teen called Eragon who one time found the dragon`s egg.</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
//этот div подстраивается под размеры content-wrapper, он не интересен в данной задаче
.book-element {
    border: 1.5px solid #aaaaaa;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 0.5%;
    font-size: 12px;

}

.content-wrapper{
    min-height: 130px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;

}
.image-wrapper {
    margin-right: 5px;

}
.image-wrapper img{

    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;

}
.text-wrapper{
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[image: Примерный рисунок того как хотелось бы]

[image: Как получается сейчас, не правильно]

Comment: чё то я запутался - что должно и как выглядеть ?

Comment: @Максим картинка снизу - то, как не должно быть. На ней картинка взяла бразды правления в свои руки и расширяет внешний блок. А нужно чтобы было примерно так как на первой картинке, только на ней не хватает вот чего - картинка должна заполнить доступное пространство, но не расширять внешний блок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам нужно сделать так, что бы картинка не влияла на размер блока. Тогда как вариант её через absolute можно.

Суть в том, что для .content-wrappe - дать align-items: stretch; (вместо center) тогда все внутренние блоки будут одной высоты. Ширину придётся задать руками

Как-то так:

```css
.book-element {
  border: 1.5px solid #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0.5%;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.content-wrapper{
  min-height: 130px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.image-wrapper {
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
}
.image-wrapper img{
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.text-wrapper{
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="book-element">
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="image-wrapper">
      <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-5kWgVN8iziQ/TV8IuMsq5MI/AAAAAAAAAaw/HW3yVOBniF0/s1600/AppleBasic.jpg" alt="bookImage"/>
    </div>
    <div class="text-wrapper">
      <div class="text-wrapper1">
        <span class="field-descr">Название: </span>Eragon<br>
        <span class="field-descr">Автор: </span>Cristofer Paoloni<br>
        <span class="field-descr">Жанр: </span>Фантастика<br>
        <span class="field-descr">Издательство: </span>хз<br>
        <span class="field-descr">Кол-во страниц: </span>100500<br>
        <span class="field-descr">ISBN: </span>123-12345-123-1-1
        123-12345-123-1-1 123-12345-123-1-1
        <br>
        <span class="field-descr">Язык: </span>Русский<br>
        <!--<span> </span>-->
        <!--<br>-->
        <!--<span></span>-->
        <!--<br>-->
      </div>
      <div class="text-wrapper2">
        <div class="description">
          <span>This is a book. This book contains some test. This text is about teen called Eragon who one time found the dragon`s egg.</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Но если есть возможность, то лучше задать её фоном для image-wrapper:

```
.image-wrapper {
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

<div class="image-wrapper" style="background-image: url(my_img.png);"></div>
```